# Does the F-Test (var.test in R) assume independence of observations?

Tags: f-test

I've looked online but I can't seem to find an answer.

Basically I'm comparing data from two groups, disease and control, and from each induvidual there's two observations. I want to compare the groups to see if one has a larger variance than the other Should I only include one observation from each individual for the test, or both? I think it should be the former but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks.

Comment: The F test in `var.test` certainly assumes independence both within and between groups. I don't think I'd do either of the things you're considering (throwing out half the data or ignoring the obvious dependence). [on other considerations, I wouldn't use the test at all, since it's *very* sensitive to the normality assumption]

Comment: Are you combining both measurements from each individual into the same sample?